# Mostrar los nuevos registros agregados

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un inconveniente, hay un datagridview que importa los registros de un archivo de excel, al mandar todos esos registros a guardar a la base de datos, verifica si existe el registro, si no existe lo agrega, si existe salta al otro registro y así sucesivamente hasta finalizar, lo que deseo que al momento de finalizar me muestre únicamente los registros nuevos que se agregaron a la base de datos en el datagridview

```
'método guardar

Public Sub Guardar(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal agregar As SqlCommand, ByVal cuenta As String)
    Dim totalreg As Integer = 0
    Dim totalgra As Integer = 0
    Try
        'recorriendo el datagridview
        For Each fila In dgv.Rows
            'asignando los valores de cada celda de la fila que se está recorriendo
            Dim monto As Double = 0
            Dim fecha As String = ""
            Dim referencia As String = ""
            Dim descripcion As String = ""
            Dim credito As String = ""
            fecha = fila.Cells("F1").Value
            referencia = fila.Cells("F2").Value
            descripcion = fila.Cells("F3").Value
            credito = fila.Cells("F4").Value
            'verificando si el registro existe
            If Not ExisteRegistro(cuenta, referencia) Then
                'limpiando los parámetros
                agregar.Parameters.Clear()
                'asignando los valores obtenidos de la fila a cada parámetro correspondiente
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuenta", cuenta)
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha))
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referencia", referencia)
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", descripcion)
                monto = convertirDolares(fecha, CDbl(credito))
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@credito", credito)
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", 1)
                'ejecutando la consuita
                agregar.ExecuteNonQuery()
                totalgra = totalgra + 1
            Else
                totalreg = totalreg + 1
                Continue For
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox("Se grabaron " + CStr(totalreg) + " transacciones y " + CStr(totalgra) + " estaban repetidos")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error debido a " + ex.ToString)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rápida para mostrar los registros nuevos sería que al detectar que no existe y lo registre, guardar ese registro en una lista y al finalizar todo el proceso de verificación, enviarle a tu **DataGridView** esa información que guardaste de los que realmente fueron tus nuevos registros.

Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y acomodes ese código para visualizarlo de mejor manera, espero te sea de ayuda, Saludos.